# Element click does not work in Firefox and IE but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

**Hi!**

I am trying to receive a file with angularjs without page reloading and with a possibility to set a name for this file dynamically.

For this I use the following block of code:

```
var filename = "my_filename.txt";
var element = angular.element('<a/>');    
element.attr({
   href: "service/download/",
   target: '_blank',
   download: filename
});
element[0].click();
```

This code works perfectly for **Google Chrome**, while it doesn't work for **Firefox** and **Internet Explorer**. In IE and FF nothing is happened after button click.

Could you please point me in the right direction? How this issue can be investigated and fixed.

- Chrome version is 35.0.1916.153
- Firefox version is 30.0
- Internet Explorer version is 10.0.9200.16899

Thanks!

Comment: can't you use `ng-click` ?

Comment: @Oliboy50 , how can I use `ng-click` in my case? Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```
var filename = "my_filename.txt";
var element = angular.element('<a/>');    
element.attr({
   href: "service/download/",
   target: '_blank',
   download: filename
});
if (document.createEvent) {
var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  ev.initMouseEvent(
    "click",
    true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */,
    window, null,
    0, 0, 0, 0, /* coordinates */
    false, false, false, false, /* modifier keys */
    0 /*left*/, null
  );
  element[0].dispatchEvent(ev);
}
else {
  element[0].fireEvent("onclick");
}
```

Comment: **Hi @Ste**
Thanks for your reply! It works for Firefox now but still doesn't work for Internet Explorer. I have made full refresh so I am sure that new code was executed.

Comment: It seems that older IE needs fireEvent method.
I edited my answer adding an alternative way for IE.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work for my Internet Explorer. My Internet Explorer version is 10.0.9200.16899.